# tooltip which brings external page in it

Tags: javascript

m looking for a tooltip which can dispaly external php page in to it and which can adjust itself up and down with respext to screen size,can some one suggest me jquery or javascript code.It should work on ajax page also.if i delete something by using ajax then tooltip should appear on ajax

Comment: tooltip should appear on ajax? didn't get you. Please specify clearly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [tooltip in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365948/tooltip-in-browser) — this is the third time you have asked the same question. Fix the first question so it asks what you want to ask, don't keep asking slightly modified copies.

Comment: ajax refresh some part of page with new content.so tooltip should appear on it

Comment: you need it for one particular control or for every control?

Comment: every control,tooltip script where the content of the tooltip is retrieved by Ajax from external files.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [jquery.cluetip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/#)
look at basic ajax,

Comment: Show us what you are doing then... Did you include the scripts etc?

Comment: i have included css and js of  jquery.cluetip which working on first page,on change of drop down i calling another page which refresh current page with new ajax page having same code of tooltip but tooltip does not appering on it

Comment: then you might have to use .live("click", function(){}); you need to show us some code

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not saying which JavaScript library you are using, I am suggesting a prototype-based solution:

**[Prototip](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip2/)**

It has many awesome features you can see on the demo page, including loading tooltips via AJAX.